# Browse truecrypt/veracrypt archive?

Tags: windows, truecrypt, veracrypt

Mounting a file archive as a system drive requires administrative permissions.

Is it possible to browse and the read files without mounting (read only is fine)? Like browsing a zip file using 7zip.

Comment: Which OS is that?

Comment: @Hannu Windows.

Comment: You can run a "portable" version of Veracrypt, but you still need access to the drivers, so my guess would be "no" - I think you have to mount it - if it was readable without mounting as a file-system, that sounds like a potential security hole of quite huge dimensions.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie How so? You still need your password/keyfile to browse it. How would browsing it after authentication be any less secure than mounting it? Infact when you mount it it stays mounted unless you unmount. With browsing it'll close as soon as you close the browser GUI window.

Comment: Well... "close the browser window" - personally, the only time I close the browser window is on reboot. Also, cache trouble. Besides, you can set the mounted volume to unmount due to various circumstances, among them time and/or time since last used.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie You still fail to make a point on how authenticated browser is any less secure than mounted option

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to browse and read files without authenticating in either TrueCrypt or VeraCrypt, because people use those programs to encrypt and securely store their passwords and other personal files, and the developers of these applications don't want anyone to be able to access this encrypted data without authenticating with the password first. If it was possible to access private information encrypted with TrueCrypt or VeraCrypt without authentication, this would be a major security breach.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you write your own readers, no. VC and TC work by mounting the files. Of course, something smart may be integrated into a file manager and allow you to see the content if the password is correct, but this is something you will have to develop. You have the TC source code available. That should make creating such a reader something easy to medium for an experienced programmer.